# How to unit test spy on $emit in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

How do I check if $emit has been called in an unit test of a directive?

My directive is fairly simple (for the purpose of illustration):

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.directive('uiList', [function () { 
    return {
        scope: {
            lengthModel: '=uiList',
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('lengthModel', function (newVal) {
                        scope.$emit('yolo');
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

so every time the attribute uiList changes, it will emit the event.

And I have unit test code as follows:

```
describe('Testing $emit in directive', function() {
  var scope;
  var element;


  //you need to indicate your module in a test
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('plunker');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.row= 1;
            spyOn(scope,'$emit');
        element = angular.element('<ul id="rows" ui-list="row">');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        });
    });

  it('should emit', function() {

    scope.$digest();
    scope.row = 2;
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("yolo");
  });
});
```

This would always give me error stating that the scope.$emit has never been called. 
Is there something wrong with the scope? Can someone please help?

Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/AqhPwp?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your directive creates an isolated scope, which is calling `$emit`,so you need to spy on this one ;)

```js
describe('Testing $emit in directive', function() {
  var scope;
  var element;
  var elementScope;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.row = 1;
      element = angular.element('<ul id="rows" ui-list="row">');
      $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
      elementScope = element.scope();
  }));

  it('should emit', function() {
    // arrange
    spyOn(elementScope, '$emit');

    // act
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.row = 2;
    });

    // assert
    expect(elementScope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("yolo");
  });
});
```

[Fixed plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iZKhH0?p=preview) :)

Comment: upvote for using the word yolo ironically in an otherwise good answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how did it work for glepetre (not sure that it does actually). For me it didn't. The thing is that the directive runs `$new` on incomming scope so the scope it creates inside and `element.scope()` are some thing different. You can check their `$id` fields. So it does not help to spy on the scope you got from `element.scope()`. I had smilar problem and had to do a little trick to make it work.

Here comes my test :

```
    beforeEach(inject(function () {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.field = null;
            scope.name = 'nolength';
        });

        spyOn(scope, '$new').and.returnValue(scope);
        spyOn(scope, '$emit');

        var element = angular.element('<my-directive name="name" field="field" title="\'Title\'" ></my-directive>');
        noLengthValidation = $compile(element)(scope);

        scope.$apply();
        elementScope = element.scope();
    }));
```

So the trick was to mock `$new` function on `scope` so instead of creating a new scope behind the scene and mess the things up it will return itself! Here comes the test itself :

```
    it('The directive should not react on string length if no max-chars attribute presented', function () {
        scope.$apply();
        noLengthValidation.isolateScope().field = 'fieldisssssssveeeeerryyyyyylooooooonnnngggggggggggggggggggggggggggg';
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ON_MORE_AWASOME_EVENT', 'nolength');
    });
```

And the the part on the directive that calls `$emit`. Just in case :

```
        function validate() {
            scope.validate = 1;
            if (scope.field) {
                if (!isValid()) {
                    scope.$emit('ON_AWASOME_EVENT', {code : scope.name, text : 'Field ' + scope.title + '  is feels bad'});
                } else {
                    scope.$emit('ON_MORE_AWASOME_EVENT', scope.name);
                }

            }
        }
```